# Switch View in different Modules using Prism and Unity

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-container, prism

I want to navigate from **ModuleA View** to **ModuleB View**. How can I implement navigation between modules?

In my application which uses Prism framework, I have two module

- **ModuleA**
- **ModuleB**

I configure two modules in my Bootstrapper like this:

```
protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog()
        {
            base.ConfigureModuleCatalog();

            ModuleCatalog moduleCatalog = (ModuleCatalog)this.ModuleCatalog;
            moduleCatalog.AddModule(typeof(ModuleA));
            moduleCatalog.AddModule(typeof(ModuleB));
        }
```

I register my both **Views** in my **ModuleA** and **ModuleB** like this:

```
public class ModuleA : IModule
    {

        private readonly IRegionManager  regionManager;
        private readonly IUnityContainer container;

        public StaffModule(IUnityContainer container, IRegionManager regionManager)
        {
            this.container     = container;
            this.regionManager = regionManager;
        }

        public void Initialize()
        {
            this.regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("MainRegion", () => this.container.Resolve<StaffView>());
         }           
    }


public class AccountModule : IModule
    {
        private readonly IRegionManager  regionManager;
        private readonly IUnityContainer container;

        public AccountModule(IUnityContainer container, IRegionManager regionManager)
        {
            this.container     = container;
            this.regionManager = regionManager;
        }

        public void Initialize()
        {
             container.RegisterType<object, AccountView>("AccountView");
            ////this.regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("MainRegion", () => this.container.Resolve<AccountView>());
        }
    }
```

When I click **Button** from **StaffView** in **ModuleA**, I want to navigate to **AccountView** in **ModuleB**. Here is my code for navigation.

```
private void LodeViewfromModule()
{
   IUnityContainer unityContainer = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IUnityContainer>();
   var regionManager=unityContainer.Resolve<IRegionManager>();
   var uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/PrismAuto.Account;component/AccountView.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
   regionManager.RequestNavigate("MainRegion", uri);
}
```

But it shows:

> System.Object exception.

Please, anyone help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you tried to navigate to `new Uri("AccountView", UriKind.Relative)`? You have registered it under that "name" after all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are registering your view for navigation using:

```
container.RegisterType<object, AccountView>("AccountView");
```

and navigating to it like:

`var uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/PrismAuto.Account;component/AccountView.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
regionManager.RequestNavigate("MainRegion", uri);`

This is wrong.  You need to navigate to it using the key your provided when you registered it for navigation:

```
regionManager.RequestNavigate("MainRegion", "AccountView");
```

Also, if you are using Prism 6 there is an extension method in the Prism.Unity namespace for registering your views for navigation like this:

```
container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<AccountView>();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that answer.